# Password Promts for "everything"

Tags: login, password, security, gui, users

I am using ubuntu 20.04.4 and after login I get password prompted for regular things and commands (starting keyboard daemon, updating system repos at startup, mounting devices, systemctl, .. I can't really name all of them).

I am not sure when the problem first occurred or where it might came from - it happened some time ago.
I couldn't find a thread fitting my problem anywhere.

I'm not sure which information could be relevant cause I'm relatively new to Linux.

what I tried so far / Info:

  - My user account has admin privileges and I'm the only user on the machine.
  - the problem occurs with or without password login
  - checked `/etc/sudoers` for `username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Thanks in advance for any tips solving the issue or upgrading the post

Comment: Are you login in with or without password?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Your question has too little information to allow suggestions. Which "every background oprtation"?